# Multi field search query in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I need to add search bar in my application. Search will search by First name and Last name. I don't know how to compose the elastcsearch query. First name and Last name are two separated fields. I am pretty new in es.

Example: 
First name: John 
Last name: Joshua

Search bar string for upper results: 
John Jo
John Jos
John Josh
Joshua John
Joshua Joh
...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) query in your search. Matches documents that have fields containing terms with a specified prefix (not analyzed). The prefix query maps to Lucene `Prefix Query`. Query structure is as follows:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "firstname": "jo"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "lastname": "jo"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Do not try wildcards, as they will not be effective in this search

Answer (score -1):

Use the next query:

```
GET /_search {
   "query": { 
     "query_string" : { 
        "query" : "firstName:jhon   
             AND  lastName: Lennon" 
      } 
    }
  }
```